Problem that Keras PointNet accepts different input formats of pointclouds when feeding with tf.data.Dataset while train
For a machine learning task I have coded with support of the internet a configurable PoinNet Version in tensorflow keras.
The keras example from PointNet I got here: https://keras.io/examples/vision/pointnet/
I am using tensorflow = "2.11.0"
What do I want?

Implemented an easy version of PointNet (see code below)
I have some stl files which I load with open3d = "^0.18.0" to convert it to PointClouds
I want to use tf.data.Dataset pipe to load the data and pre- and postprocess it
I want to predict a certain curve/values on the end, depending on the input (but this is not the problem)
For simplicity and clarity I implemented two options: 1. Load all pointcloud data in one numpy array before training AND 2.Load pointcloud data while training via tf.py_function

My Problem

When using option 2 (load pointcloud data while training via tf.py_function): regardless of the number of points in a point cloud, the data is passed through the neural network, although it does not match the INPUT_SHAPE from the neural net
When I use option 1 (load all pointclouds before training and then build the tf.data.Dataset pipe): everything works as expected. If the pointcloud shape does not match the INPUT_SHAPE of the neural net, an error occurs.
Why is there the strange behavior? Is it because of the usage of tf.py_function?

My code block for the PointNet
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import open3d as o3d
import pandas as pd
import random

##############################################################################################
# define constants

NUM_POINTS = 20
INPUT_SHAPE = [20, 3]
BATCHSIZE = 6
NUM_CLASSES = 10
NUM_SAMPLES = 6
WHICH_LOADING = "all"  # all, single_py_function

PATH_FOLDER = "data/few_examples/stl_examples/"

##############################################################################################
# define loading functions


def load_all_pointclouds(list_filepaths):

    list_arrays = []
    for path in list_filepaths:
        mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh(path)
        pointcloud = mesh.sample_points_poisson_disk(
            number_of_points=NUM_POINTS, init_factor=5
        )
        array_pointcloud = np.asarray(pointcloud.points)
        list_arrays.append(array_pointcloud)
        print("array_pointcloud.shape: ", array_pointcloud.shape)

    arrays_pointcloud = np.array(list_arrays)
    return arrays_pointcloud


def load_single_pointcloud(filepath):
    filepath = filepath.numpy().decode("utf-8")
    mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh(filepath)
    pointcloud = mesh.sample_points_poisson_disk(
        number_of_points=NUM_POINTS, init_factor=5
    )
    array_pointcloud = np.asarray(pointcloud.points)
    array_pointcloud = np.float32(array_pointcloud)
    array_pointcloud = tf.ensure_shape(array_pointcloud, INPUT_SHAPE)
    print("array_pointcloud.shape: ", array_pointcloud.shape)
    return array_pointcloud
    
##############################################################################################
### create filepaths

list_files = os.listdir(PATH_FOLDER)
list_filepaths = [PATH_FOLDER + x for x in list_files]

### create y data

df_y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(NUM_SAMPLES, NUM_CLASSES))
ds_y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df_y)

### logic for loading while train or preload all data

if WHICH_LOADING == "single_py_function":
    df_3d = pd.DataFrame(list_filepaths)
    ds_3d = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df_3d)

    ds_3d = ds_3d.map(
        lambda filepath: tf.py_function(
            load_single_pointcloud, [filepath[0]], Tout=tf.float32
        )
    )


if WHICH_LOADING == "all":
    arr_3d = load_all_pointclouds(list_filepaths)
    ds_3d = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(arr_3d)

### zip datasets and postprocess data

ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds_3d, ds_y))
ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=1000, seed=42).batch(BATCHSIZE).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)


### check ds data

for i, element in enumerate(ds.as_numpy_iterator()):
    print("array_pointcloud.type: ", type(element[0]))
    print("array_pointcloud.shape: ", element[0].shape)
    print("y.shape", element[1].shape)


### Build a model


def conv_bn(x, filters):
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters, kernel_size=1, padding="valid")(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.0)(x)
    return layers.Activation("relu")(x)


def dense_bn(x, filters):
    x = layers.Dense(filters)(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.0)(x)
    return layers.Activation("relu")(x)


class OrthogonalRegularizer(keras.regularizers.Regularizer):
    def __init__(self, num_features, l2reg=0.001):
        self.num_features = num_features
        self.l2reg = l2reg
        self.eye = tf.eye(num_features)

    def __call__(self, x):
        x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, self.num_features, self.num_features))
        xxt = tf.tensordot(x, x, axes=(2, 2))
        xxt = tf.reshape(xxt, (-1, self.num_features, self.num_features))
        return tf.reduce_sum(self.l2reg * tf.square(xxt - self.eye))


def tnet(inputs, num_features):
    # Initalise bias as the indentity matrix
    bias = keras.initializers.Constant(np.eye(num_features).flatten())
    reg = OrthogonalRegularizer(num_features)

    x = conv_bn(inputs, 32)
    x = conv_bn(x, 64)
    x = conv_bn(x, 512)
    x = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
    x = dense_bn(x, 256)
    x = dense_bn(x, 128)
    x = layers.Dense(
        num_features * num_features,
        kernel_initializer="zeros",
        bias_initializer=bias,
        activity_regularizer=reg,
    )(x)
    feat_T = layers.Reshape((num_features, num_features))(x)
    return layers.Dot(axes=(2, 1))([inputs, feat_T])


inputs = keras.Input(shape=INPUT_SHAPE)

x = tnet(inputs, 3)
x = conv_bn(x, 32)
x = conv_bn(x, 32)
x = tnet(x, 32)
x = conv_bn(x, 32)
x = conv_bn(x, 64)
x = conv_bn(x, 512)
x = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
x = dense_bn(x, 256)
x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = dense_bn(x, 128)
x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)

outputs = layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation="softmax")(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="pointnet")

### compile and fit data

# model.summary()
model.compile(
    loss="mse",
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
)

model.fit(ds, epochs=2)

Print Results on different configurations
Configuration 1 - loading all before train works fine when shapes match
NUM_POINTS = 20
INPUT_SHAPE = [20, 3]
BATCHSIZE = 6
WHICH_LOADING = "all_before"

Print Result for Config 1
array_pointcloud.shape in load_all_pointclouds function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_all_pointclouds function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_all_pointclouds function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_all_pointclouds function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_all_pointclouds function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_all_pointclouds function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.type in dataset loop:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
array_pointcloud.shape in dataset loop:  (6, 20, 3)
y.shape in dataset loop (6, 10)
INPUT_SHAPE neural net:  [20, 3]
NUM_POINTS predefined:  20
BATCHSIZE predefined:  6
Epoch 1/2
1/1 [==============================] - 9s 9s/step - loss: 0.7237
Epoch 2/2
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step - loss: 0.6924

Configuration 2 - loading all before train throws error as expected when shapes do not match
NUM_POINTS = 21
INPUT_SHAPE = [20, 3]
BATCHSIZE = 6
WHICH_LOADING = "all_before"

Print Result for Config 2
array_pointcloud.shape in load_all_pointclouds function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_all_pointclouds function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_all_pointclouds function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_all_pointclouds function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_all_pointclouds function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_all_pointclouds function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.type in dataset loop:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
array_pointcloud.shape in dataset loop:  (6, 21, 3)
y.shape in dataset loop (6, 10)
INPUT_SHAPE neural net:  [20, 3]
NUM_POINTS predefined:  21
BATCHSIZE predefined:  6

Error message for Config 2
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "pointnet" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 20, 3), found shape=(None, 21, 3)

Configuration 3 - loading while train works fine when shapes match
NUM_POINTS = 20
INPUT_SHAPE = [20, 3]
BATCHSIZE = 6
WHICH_LOADING = "single_py_function_while_train"

Print Result for Config 3
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.type in dataset loop:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
array_pointcloud.shape in dataset loop:  (6, 20, 3)
y.shape in dataset loop (6, 10)
INPUT_SHAPE neural net:  [20, 3]
NUM_POINTS predefined:  20
BATCHSIZE predefined:  6
Epoch 1/2
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (20, 3)
1/1 [==============================] - 16s 16s/step - loss: 0.5778
Epoch 2/2
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (20, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (20, 3)
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 193ms/step - loss: 0.5620

Configuration 4 - loading while train does not work as expected if shapes do not match. It should throw an error. But it does not.
NUM_POINTS = 21
INPUT_SHAPE = [20, 3]
BATCHSIZE = 6
WHICH_LOADING = "single_py_function_while_train"

Print Result for Config 3
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.type in dataset loop:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
array_pointcloud.shape in dataset loop:  (6, 21, 3)
y.shape in dataset loop (6, 10)
INPUT_SHAPE neural net:  [20, 3]
NUM_POINTS predefined:  21
BATCHSIZE predefined:  6
Epoch 1/2
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (21, 3)
1/1 [==============================] - 13s 13s/step - loss: 0.6657
Epoch 2/2
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (21, 3)
array_pointcloud.shape in load_single_pointcloud function:  (21, 3)
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 64ms/step - loss: 0.6431

Conclusion
So, how is it possible that a tf neural net can be successful trained, although the data shape and the input shape does not match when loading and feeding data while train? Is it because of the usage of tf.py_function?
Thanks for help.
